# Powershell Returning Results in Batches

Tags: powershell, office365

I have the below office365 command which I could do with some pointers on if possible.

```
$GetUsersIDs = Get-MsolUser | Where-Object {($_.licenses).AccountSkuId -match "STANDARDWOFFPACK_STUDENT"} | Select -ExpandProperty UserPrincipalName
Grant-CsUserPolicyPackage -identity $GetUsersIDs -PackageName "Education_PrimaryStudent_RemoteLearning"
```

I want it to return the first 10 results and run a command then return the next 10 results and run a command and so on. The reason behind this is due to Microsoft limitations only allowing you to run the command in batches of X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a `for` loop that increments by 10. Since your user list will be a collection, you can use a combination of indexing and the range operator `..` to output in batches.

```
$GetUsersIDs = Get-MsolUser | Where-Object {($_.licenses).AccountSkuId -match "STANDARDWOFFPACK_STUDENT"} |
    Select -ExpandProperty UserPrincipalName
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $GetUsersIDs.Count; $i += 10) {
    Grant-CsUserPolicyPackage -Identity $GetUsersIDs[$i..($i+9)] -PackageName "Education_PrimaryStudent_RemoteLearning"
}
```

Note that the [Grant-CsUserPolicyPackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/grant-csuserpolicypackage?view=teams-ps) command allows updates in batches of 20.